# Deploy an Angular application

Tags: sql, .net, angular, web-deployment

How do I deploy an web application which was developed using Angular, .Net and SQL? In short we have developed an application locally no idea how to make it available for public?

Comment: For that you need a Server, There are various ways: `IIS Server, Azure`

Comment: So do we have to buy an azure server and do you have any idea about AWS servers?

Comment: are you working for a firm or it is your personal project?

Comment: Actually it is for my friend for his local business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS S3 for deploying the Angular application as a static website. But that will be over HTTP only. You might want to use AWS CloudFront to make your content available over HTTPS.

OR

You can get a Linux EC2 instance and deploy you angular and .Net core apps on an apache server. A lot of articles are available for the same online. In case you are using .Net 4.X frameworks then get a Windows EC2 instance from AWS and deploy your apps there as old .Net 4.x f/w do not work on Linux machines.

For SQL, AWS provides RDS instances. Do remember that AWS is not entirely free and they might charge you after you cross the free usage limits. Read the guidelines very carefully.